# Can i create a trigger for every condition that satisfies in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, triggers, database-trigger

I'm having a trouble regarding my school project. I am making a payroll system with 300 employees. Now, I'm having a problem regarding computing the salary of each employee. I came up with an idea of making a trigger every time the employee will timeout/logout and compute the salary of each employee per day and store it in database to reduce the query load of the system. Is it possible to make a trigger every-time each employee will timeout/logout and i will create a query inside the trigger to compute/insert the salary of employee per day?. Or any idea/suggestions to solve my problem ?

Comment: The parameters of the problem are inadequately defined. However, the 'query load' on a database comprising just 300 employees must be negligible.

Comment: It will not make any difference with respect to server load, etc. The queries fired from triggers would be same as that on scripting side. Calculate the per day salary on `PHP` side and update. Since you will already be updating the logout time, add the salary column in there too. Triggers come handy when your application is huge where you would require to make changes at lot of places due to dependency.

Comment: @Samir do you mean everytime i will calculate the day salary, each computation i will store to database?

Comment: @Strawberry can you suggest me any suggestion on what should i do for this problem ?

Comment: @JcJohn, Yes that's right.

Comment: Don't store derived data. Whenever someone wants to know something about earnings, they can simply execute an appropriate query.